# Need to clean up disk space

Tags: disk-usage

I'm running ubuntu 13.04 which is not supported anymore. I want to install updates and clean up disk space in boot.  How do I do this? What command should I use.

Comment: This is a pretty thorough post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

> deb http ://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
>
> deb-src http ://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
>
> deb http ://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main
>   restricted
>
> deb-src http ://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main
>   restricted
>
> deb http ://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe multiverse
>
> deb-src http ://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
>   multiverse
>
> deb http ://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main
>   restricted
>
> deb-src http ://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main
>   restricted

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Answer (score 0):

1.-clean first

```
sudo apt-get -s clean
```

"Remove all this files"
( /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin
/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin)

```
sudo apt-get autoremove  --purge
```

(clean all old package installed before)

```
sudo dpkg 'linux-image *' --list
```

(clean all old linux kernel)

2.-Update

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off by backing up your data (and /etc), checking the back up and doing a clean install of 20.04.1 LTS to clean up and refresh your system. This would allow you re-format and re-partition your disc(s) and partitions.

If you want to re-install your existing (available packages) this [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) will be of some use, as it includes how to re-install on a new version.